# Alternative types in type theory

Tags: type-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three different types. Can I define a new type $C$ as $C:=A|B$?

If not, How can I define alternative types using "type theory"?

I just want to say that $C$ is equal by definition to either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: What specific type theory are you working in?

Comment: In most dependent type theories I know of, you would be able to define $C$ as a type dependent on a boolean parameter which is equal by definition to either $A$ or $B$ depending on the parameter.

Comment: You are probably looking for a [coproduct type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) $A + B$, also called a sum type or (in programming languages) a tagged union.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a coproduct type.